# Android: Fill the screen vertically and leave space at top and bottom

Tags: android, android-layout

I am creating a game and my splash image of .9.png should be filling the screen vertically  (orientation is potrait) but leave a small border space at the top and the bottom of the screen but it does the opposite in terms of the border spacing, it leaves the spacing at the sides of the splash image.

here is my splashscreen.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ImageView  android:id="@+id/splashScreenImage"
    android:src="@drawable/starfighter"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</ImageView>
<TextView 
android:text="game by: alphy poxy - graphics by: alpho07"
android:id="@+id/creditsText"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TextView>
</FrameLayout>
```

part of my manifest file

```
  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.space_fighter.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="SFMainMenu" android:screenOrientation="portrait">      </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on the image you specify.

If you specify `scaleType="centerInside"` for your `ImageView` then the image will fit into the allocated space keeping the xy-ratio. So if you point to an image that is of the desired image ratio you will achieve the effect you want.

Refer to [this site](http://etcodehome.blogspot.com/2011/05/android-imageview-scaletype-samples.html) for examples of how to use `scaleType`.

Comment: Thanks, this fills the whole screen, is there a way i can leave some little space both at the top and the bottom of the image?

Comment: @Alphy Add margin or padding, though I am not entirely sure the padding will work with `centerInside`. Whatever, though, keep in mind that the state depends mostly on the kind of image you specify for the `ImageView`